# How ti create a decision prompt for a loop with python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, loops, decision-tree

I am trying to create a decision prompt for a loop with python 3.6. But it does not work

```
def cycle():
looping = "yes"
while looping == "No" or "no" or "n" or "N":
    looping = input('Do you want to make a new calculation? \n \t (Y/N)')
    if looping == "No" or "no" or "n" or "N":
        looping = "yes"
        break
    elif looping != "No" or "no" or "n" or "N":
        print('This is not the right answer')
        looping="no"
```

Can somebody help me out with this code?
Thank you!

Comment: I don't know Python, but in most programming languages where your `if` statement isn't a syntax error, the meaning of `or "no"` is not what you seem to think it is. It does not compare those values to `looping`. You need to repeat the comparison, i.e., `looping == "No" or looping == "no"` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as the comparison error that Jean-François Fabre pointed out, there's a logic error here too. To simplify a little bit, this is the code in your example:

```
looping = "yes"
while looping == "no":
    (do stuff which might change looping to something else)
```

The `while` loop never starts. You should write:

```
looping = "no"
while looping == "no":
    (do stuff)
```

or as Jean-François said,

```
looping = "no"
while looping.lower() in ["no","n"]:
    (do stuff)
```

Then you're converting someone's "No" answer into a "yes"...?

Why not try staying in the loop forever unless the user provides valid input:

```
def cycle():
    newcalc = "no"
    while True:
        newcalc = input('Do you want to make a new calculation? \n \t (Y/N)')
        if newcalc.lower() in ["no","n"]:
            newcalc = "no"
            break
        if newcalc.lower() in ["yes","y"]:
            newcalc = "yes"
            break
        print('This is not the right answer')
```

Comment: (fyi, I'm not a Python programmer, apologies if this is nonsense!)

Answer (score 1):

you cannot compare strings like that:

```
while looping == "No" or "no" or "n" or "N": # wrong
```

Basically the trailing `or` statements just check if `"no"` is not empty, etc.. they're useless.

- If `looping=="No"`, you'll get `True`: loop continues
- If `looping!="No"`, you'll get the next "non-False": `"no"`: loop continues

correct way: converting to lowercase, and test if string belongs to a list:

```
while looping.lower() in ["no","n"]:
```